# YouTube video autoplay in mobile view not counting

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I was trying to add autoplay YouTube video in my web page. But it wasn't autoplaying in mobile. Then i got a solution form here. That .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    </head>
  <body>
<!-- 1. The <iframe> (video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      width: '100%',
      videoId: 'osz5tVY97dQ',
      playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'playsinline': 1 },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
     event.target.mute();
    event.target.playVideo();
  }
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code helped me to autoplay YouTube video in mobile. But the video view is not counting in youtube. Can you guys help me with this

Comment: is the views number of your video 301  ?

Comment: No. I tried a lot of YouTube videos. The problem is same.

Comment: @SanaulDey if I recall correctly, I read about YouTube only considers a *view* is valid when user interaction is detected, so, unless the user has more interaction with the video (*scrolling, like/dislike the video, commenting, etc*), then, it wont be considered a valid user interaction.